# Do not drop and create database when scripting drop/create database objects and data with mssql-scripter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, mssql-scripter

I'm trying to script the database objects and data of my database to later move it to a server where I don't have backup/restore rights. Instead I'm using the Generate Scripts method and I use [mssql-scripter](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter) to generate the scripts.

I have a .bat file with the following script code to generate my SQL script file.

> set 
>   timevar=%date:~4,2%*%date:~7,2%*%date:~10,4%-%time:~0,2%*%time:~3,2%*%time:~6,2%
>
> mssql-scripter --server 10.100.8.8 -d Dev_db -f .\%timevar%.sql
>   --schema-and-data --script-drop-create --target-server-version 2016 --target-server-edition Standard --check-for-existence --include-dependencies --constraint-names --collation -U ScriptingUser -P 1234 --exclude-use-database

The problem is that it's also scripting `DROP DATABASE` and `CREATE DATABASE`, which I don't want. I would only like to `DROP` and `CREATE` database objects and later populate tables with the scripted data.

Has anyone faced this problem and have you found a solution?

Comment: Have you tried `--exclude-objects` option?

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко Well, the database is an object that contains everything else. So excluding it will just result in not exporting anything I'm interested in. Which it does, actually it just throws an error if I try to exclude the database name.

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко I managed to find a solution, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around with the options for longer, I managed to find the right parameter and work-around to solve my problem.

The exact code that I ran is:

> set
>   timevar=%date:~4,2%*%date:~7,2%*%date:~10,4%-%time:~0,2%*%time:~3,2%*%time:~6,2%
>
> mssql-scripter --server 10.100.8.8 -d Dev_db -f .\%timevar%.sql --schema-and-data
>   --script-drop-create --target-server-version 2016 --target-server-edition Standard --check-for-existence --constraint-names --collation -U ScriptingUser -P 1234 --exclude-use-database --include-objects "dbo." --display-progress

The key change I added the **--include-objects** parameter, with a twist. The way I changed by scripts is by **adding** code snippet:

> --include-objects **"dbo."**

This tells mssql-scripter to only script out objects that contain the "**dbo.**" keyword(substring) in the fully qualified name.

Also I **remove** this parameter from my initial command:

> --include-dependencies

since I script out everything in my database under the dbo schema.

This scripts out:

- all of the objects in my database
- it includes a IF EXISTS check
- it issues a DROP query to drop the existing
- it issues a CREATE query to create the new one
- it issues multiple INSERT statements to also populate the database with data